# "Directory is expected, not a file." error when using Azure CLI to download from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I have this in my CI/CD pipeline:

```
az storage blob download-batch --destination "extraction" --source azure_container --auth-mode login --account-name az_account_name
```

When running it (as part of my full pipeline), I get this:

```
ERROR:[Errno 20] Not a directory:'extraction/config-0000/scripts' 
Directory is expected, not a file.
```

I dont get why. config-0000 is a directory in the container azure_container. Inside, we have folder, which contain folder, which contain json files.

I just want to download the full folder structure and files from within the container.

Ironically, uploading via `az storage blob upload-batch` works like a charm...

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path for the destination folder ?

Comment: thanks for you comment. I tried but end up with the same error. I dont know if relevant, but I am running it as part of a gitlab pipeline. But eben there, if I specify the full path, doesnt help.

I found a workaround now, which is to loop through every file and use "az storage blob download" to download it, but that takes forever.

Comment: @LeoFr If you figured a workaround or an answer post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to download the full folder structure and files from within the container.

The error "Directory is expected, not a file" tells that the destination path specified in the `--destination` parameter is not a directory. Also, check the `extractionfolder` in the same directory which you're running the command on your system.

In my environment, I have the Blob structure in my storage account.

```hs
a/abc
   05-03-2024.html
c/abc/employee
     temp.png
d/abc/employee
   mountainview.png 
g/abc
  bike.png
```

Now, using the same command, I can download all files and folders from the Azure Blob storage.

**Command:**

```
az storage blob download-batch --destination "important" --source "sample" --account-name "venkat678" --auth-mode "login"
```

The above command is executed and downloads the exact structure in my environment.

**Output:**

```
PS C:\Users\v-vsettu> az storage blob download-batch --destination "important" --source "sample" --account-name "venkat678" --auth-mode "login" 2> $null
[
  "a/abc/05-03-2024.html",
  "c/abc/employee/temp.png",
  "d/abc/employee/mountainview.png",
  "g/abc/bike.png"
]
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**
[az storage blob | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch)

Comment: many thanks for your detailed answer.

Maybe its a problem that I am running it via a gitlab pipeline. "Problem" meaning the folder structure indeed is not as I expect it.

let me take another, closer look at it.

Comment: Of course! But so far it didnt solve anything for me, except pointing me in a possible failure reason. So for now I will need to continue investigating.